# Bool query where the one of the "should"s is a "not" in Elasticsearc

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to use a bool query where one of the conditions (in the should section, for example) is a negation of something.

Specifically:

1) a field does not exists. For example, i tried the query:

```
{"query":{
            "bool":{
                    "must":[
                            {"match":{"field1":"val1"}},
                            ],
                    "should":[
                                {"match":{"field2":"val2"}},
                                {"filtered" : 
                                            {
                                             "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
                                             "filter" : {"missing" : { "field":"field3"}}
                                             }
                                 },
                                ],
                    "minimum_number_should_match":1
                    }
         }
}
```

2) a field does not have a value. For example:

```
{"query":{
            "bool":{
                    "must":[
                            {"match":{"field1":"val1"}},
                            ],
                    "should":[
                                {"match":{"field2":"val2"}},
                                {"filtered" : 
                                            {
                                             "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
                                             "filter" : {"not" : { "field3":"val3"}}
                                             }
                                 },
                                ],
                    "minimum_number_should_match":1
                    }
         }
}
```

both do not work. I must be applying a filter or inserting the inner query wrong.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure this is exactly answering the original question, but it's similar and verified via the counts lining up from running the two queries separately. This finds somefield that is null or true:

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "filter" : {
            "or" : [
                { "missing" : { "field" : "somefield" } },
                { "term" : {  "somefield" : "true" } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck. JSON query languages make me miss SQL!

Answer (score 1):

I have only successfully used the **missing** and **not** filters outside of a bool query.

For example:

```
"filtered_query":{
  "query":{
    "bool":{ ... }
  },
  {"filter": {
    "missing":{ ... }
  }
}
```

You are not going to get any scoring on that condition (just results 'filtered-out' or not), though you don't explicitly say you need scoring.

You might want to take a look at the docs for the **missing** filter for both your stated requirements, since it allows you to check for fields that don't exist, or don't have a value. I don't think the **not** function is doing what you expect in your second example. For reference: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/missing-filter/

```
"missing" : { 
     "field" : "user",
     "existence" : true,
     "null_value" : true
}
```

Make sure you use the existence and null_value attributes appropriately to indicate whether you want a missing field to be matched ("existence": true) or an empty / null value to be matched ("null_value": true)

Comment: I was trying to use missing or not inside of a bool and couldn't get it either.